# Vendor.js file node modules split into chunks

Tags: angular, webpack, vendor

I am kind of new to Angular. I am using angular 8 right now. Vendor.js file is automatically created(Vendor.8578d78.js). According to some research I did, it contains everything from the Node Modules folder. For example the Node Modules folder contains lodash, hammer and graphql etc.
My question is, is there a way I can split the vendor file that is automatically created. for example lodash is not created automatically in the vendor file but it is created in a separate vendor file.
Thanks

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I just want to know how can we do it, plus it will also decrease the size of the vendor file and we will also have a separate vendor file for our ticketing module that uses its own libraries.